# Can't access an async function's response

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, ipfs

I can't seem to find a way to access a value from an async value as it always returns undefined, I would like to wait for the function to end and then retrieve the value but it's not working...

```
  async UploadFile(file): Promise<any> {

      let ipfsId: any
      const fileStream = fileReaderPullStream(file)
      await this.ipfs.add(fileStream, { progress: (prog) => console.log(`received: ${prog}`) })
      .then((response) => {
        ipfsId = response[0].hash
        console.log(ipfsId)
        return ipfsId
        //window.open("localhost:8080/ipfs/" + ipfsId);
        //window.open("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/" + ipfsId);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      }) 

  }
```

And this is my call:

```
  uploadFile(event) {

    const fileSelected: File = event.target.files[0];
    (async() => {
    this.temp_ipfs_hash = await this.IPFS.UploadFile(fileSelected)
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    console.log(this.temp_ipfs_hash)
    })()

  }
```

I'd like to access the return value but it's always returning me undefined or error value... 
Anyone has any idea what I could try here ?

Thank you so much for your time! :)

Edit: I had no idea it was wrong to post images, so sorry, I've changed it! sorry! :(

Comment: Always post your code instead of  adding images

Comment: More precisely, post your code as text, so that users will be able to copy/paste it easily. See [this guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on formatting code blocks

Comment: I've changed it, I'm so sorry, I had no idea :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using both promise based then and async await simultaneously, your upload file function should either return a promise and then resolve reject it appropriately or if you want to stick to async-await mechanism then your upload file function will have to changed. Here is how async await should be used, assume that foobar is an asynchronous function like your ipfs.add

```
async function foo() {
  let results = await foobar();
  return results;
}
```

Here is how you will call such foo

```
async function bar() {
  let fooResults = await foo();
  console.log(fooResults);
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly like this, I had no idea it worked like that, thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

- UploadFile should return a promise, it's currently returning nothing.
  In order to chain promises, you should replace the last line by

  `return this.ifps.add(...).then(...).catch(...);`

---

- Alternative using await: return await which is the result value returned by the promise

  `return await this.ifps.add(...).then(...).catch(...);`

  In the caller, you can log the result as if there was no promise:

  `console.log(this.UploadFile(fileSelected));`